# can we use web3j and the experimental ABIEncoderV2?

Tags: spring, ethereum, web3-java

I developed a Dapp using nodejs with web3js API, and I used the experimental ABIEncoderV2 features.

Now I want to migrate to spring instead of nodejs, so I will use the web3j module, but I am not sure that it supports the "experimental ABIEncoderV2"

can anyone tell me if is supported or no ?

cause there is nothing about that in the [github repo](https://github.com/web3j/web3j-spring-boot-starter)

Answer (score 2):

web3j does not support the experimental ABI encoder yet, so no structs can be used as function parameters.

There is an open (and funded) [issue](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/368) to implement it, but is still on development.